# Force validation rules for controls bound on unselected tabItems in WPF

Tags: wpf, validation, data-binding, wpf-controls

In my canonical example, I have two tabs the first with a button and the second with a text box that is bound to a validation rule. When the button is clicked an action occurs that should cause the validation to fail and therefore the Validation.Error event to fire. However, the event will only fire when I click the second tab.

The reason this is so important to me is I have a form with complex validation that occurs across multiple tabs and I want to highlight those tabs containing errors in some - and I especially want to display the errors when the form first loads.

I've already used [a technique](http://graemehill.ca/forcing-form-validation-in-wpf-before-user-input) to force the validation to fire when the form loads but I just don't know why when the forms loaded it doesn't fire when the button is clicked.

The XAML for my test case :

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.TabsDemo"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="Tabs" Height="300" Width="300" Validation.Error="Window_Error">

    <TabControl Grid.Row="0">
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>First</TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Margin="5">
                    <Button Click="Button_Click">Clear the second textbox</Button>
                </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>MyDataItem</TabItem.Header>
            <TextBox>
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <local:ValidationBinding Path="MyDataItem" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                        <local:ValidationBinding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:ValidateText />
                        </local:ValidationBinding.ValidationRules>
                    </local:ValidationBinding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

My code behind :

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class TabsDemo : Window
    {
        public TabsDemo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MyViewModel();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (DataContext as MyViewModel).MyDataItem = String.Empty;
        }

        private void Window_Error(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Validation Error : " + e.Error.RuleInError);
        }
    }

    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {       
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private string _myDataItem = "Default Value";
        public string MyDataItem
        {
            get { return _myDataItem; }
            set
            {
                if (_myDataItem != value)
                {
                    _myDataItem = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyDataItem"));
                }
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, args);
        }
    }
}
```

And for completeness here's the validation binding markup extension :

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ValidationBinding : MarkupExtension
    {
        private readonly Binding _binding = new Binding();
        private DependencyObject _dependencyObject;
        private DependencyProperty _dependencyProperty;

        public ValidationBinding()
        {
            _binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
            _binding.ValidatesOnExceptions = true;
            _binding.NotifyOnValidationError = true;
        }

        public ValidationBinding(string path)
        {
            _binding.Path = new PropertyPath(path);
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var valueTarget = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;
            _dependencyObject = valueTarget.TargetObject as DependencyObject;
            _dependencyProperty = valueTarget.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;

            var element = _dependencyObject as FrameworkElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                if (element.IsLoaded)
                    ForceValidation();
                else
                    element.Loaded += (sender, args) => ForceValidation();
            }
            else
            {
                ForceValidation();
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("MarkupExtension.ProvideValue called for element " + element.Name);
            return _binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        }

        private void ForceValidation()
        {
            BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(_dependencyObject, _dependencyProperty).UpdateSource();
        }

        public object FallbackValue
        {
            get { return _binding.FallbackValue; }
            set { _binding.FallbackValue = value; }
        }

        public string StringFormat
        {
            get { return _binding.StringFormat; }
            set { _binding.StringFormat = value; }
        }

        public object TargetNullValue
        {
            get { return _binding.TargetNullValue; }
            set { _binding.TargetNullValue = value; }
        }

        public string BindingGroupName
        {
            get { return _binding.BindingGroupName; }
            set { _binding.BindingGroupName = value; }
        }

        public Collection<ValidationRule> ValidationRules
        {
            get { return _binding.ValidationRules; }
        }

        public bool ValidatesOnExceptions
        {
            get { return _binding.ValidatesOnExceptions; }
            set { _binding.ValidatesOnExceptions = value; }
        }

        public bool ValidatesOnDataErrors
        {
            get { return _binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors; }
            set { _binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = value; }
        }

        public PropertyPath Path
        {
            get { return _binding.Path; }
            set { _binding.Path = value; }
        }

        public string XPath
        {
            get { return _binding.XPath; }
            set { _binding.XPath = value; }
        }

        public BindingMode Mode
        {
            get { return _binding.Mode; }
            set { _binding.Mode = value; }
        }

        public UpdateSourceTrigger UpdateSourceTrigger
        {
            get { return _binding.UpdateSourceTrigger; }
            set { _binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = value; }
        }

        public bool NotifyOnSourceUpdated
        {
            get { return _binding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated; }
            set { _binding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated = value; }
        }

        public bool NotifyOnTargetUpdated
        {
            get { return _binding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated; }
            set { _binding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated = value; }
        }

        public bool NotifyOnValidationError
        {
            get { return _binding.NotifyOnValidationError; }
            set { _binding.NotifyOnValidationError = value; }
        }

        public IValueConverter Converter
        {
            get { return _binding.Converter; }
            set { _binding.Converter = value; }
        }

        public object ConverterParameter
        {
            get { return _binding.ConverterParameter; }
            set { _binding.ConverterParameter = value; }
        }

        public CultureInfo ConverterCulture
        {
            get { return _binding.ConverterCulture; }
            set { _binding.ConverterCulture = value; }
        }

        public object Source
        {
            get { return _binding.Source; }
            set { _binding.Source = value; }
        }

        public RelativeSource RelativeSource
        {
            get { return _binding.RelativeSource; }
            set { _binding.RelativeSource = value; }
        }

        public string ElementName
        {
            get { return _binding.ElementName; }
            set { _binding.ElementName = value; }
        }

        public bool IsAsync
        {
            get { return _binding.IsAsync; }
            set { _binding.IsAsync = value; }
        }

        public object AsyncState
        {
            get { return _binding.AsyncState; }
            set { _binding.AsyncState = value; }
        }

        public bool BindsDirectlyToSource
        {
            get { return _binding.BindsDirectlyToSource; }
            set { _binding.BindsDirectlyToSource = value; }
        }

        public UpdateSourceExceptionFilterCallback UpdateSourceExceptionFilter
        {
            get { return _binding.UpdateSourceExceptionFilter; }
            set { _binding.UpdateSourceExceptionFilter = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possibly because on TextBox you set `UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"`, try  set it to OnPpropertyChanged`